# ZZ plant not growing

Tags: houseplants, zzplant

[image]I took a stem with several leaves from a ZZ plant and put it in water, it put out some roots. Over two years ago I put it in a pot with soil, it died back and produced the single stem you see in the image. It has stayed this way for at least two years - will it ever grow?

Comment: No image Jim. If the plant has solid (not flacid) roots and green growth at the base of the surviving leaf, it should survive. Plants sometimes take 2-3 years to “settle in” and begin to grow. If you can update (Edit) your question to include information on the region you live, the location of the plant in your home, SO may be able to provide better advice. Try applying half strength liquid seaweed tonic every 3-4 weeks in the warmer months (=growing season).

Comment: Please add a photo, if possible...

Comment: Welcome Jim! Our picture posting system can be difficult! What happens when you try to upload it? Is there an error message? If so, what does it say? Is the picture on your computer, or is it uploaded to something like a Google pictures or Imgur folder?   If it's in an online album, one of us can usually download it for you! If it's on your computer, let us know and we'll walk you through the process. Don't give up!

Comment: Sorry, I've been away from the site.  I am looking now at how I can re-upload the image, but don't see anything that allows me to do that.  I will keep searching for a way.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: My large Zamioculcas took over a year to recover from being split and repotted. The plants may just be picy about root disturbance.